# PHP passing an array into a SQL query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I create an array from checkboxes that are "checked" via JS.

**Simple Checkboxes:**

```
     <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkSearch[]" value="One" checked /> One
          </label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkSearch[]" value="Two" checked /> Two
          </label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkSearch[]" value="Three" checked /> Three
          </label>
      </div>
```

**JS:**

```
        var selectedItems = [];
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
                selectedItems .push($(this).val());
        });

        //passing array in a function
        searchLocations(pass1, pass2, selectedItems);
```

**At this point what is outputted is (assuming all three checkboxes are "checked"):**

*["One", "Two", "Three"];*

Here's where I'm not quite sure what needs to happen next?

Can I include the array as a URL string and use the PHP .implode function later on within my SQL statement?

Here's what I've tried:

```
function searchLocations(pass1, pass2, selectedItems) {
var searchUrl = 'searchLocations.php?pass1=' + pass1 + '&pass2=' + pass2 + '&selectedItems=' + selectedItems;
...
}
```

**searchLocations.php**

```
$pass1 = $_GET['pass1'];
$pass2 = $_GET['pass2'];
$selectedItems = $_GET['selectedItems'];
$selectedItems = "  '".implode("', '", $selectedItems)."'  ";

$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE pass1 = $pass1 AND pass2 = $pass2 AND selectedItems IN ($selectedItems)");
```

$selectedItems needs to read like this in the SQL query:  IN ('One', 'Two', 'Three')..

Comment: I sure hope `sprintf()` sanitizes those `$_GET` params

Comment: Your `$_GET['selectedItems']` is *not* an array.  It's a string.  Have a look at `var_dump($_GET['selectedItems']);`.  You might need to `explode()` it first.  You can also use jQuery to create the query string for you: `var searchUrl = 'searchLocations.php?'+$param({pass1: pass1, pass2: pass2, selectedItems: selectedItems});`  If you do this then `$_GET['selectedItems']` will be an array and your code should work.

Comment: Why are you using `sprintf`, without any `%s`?  This is a ***very unsafe*** piece of code.  You should be using prepared statements, or at the very least actually *escaping* the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function that implodes and allows you to wrap elements:

```
function implode_wrapped($before, $after, $glue, $array) 
{
    $out = '';
    foreach ( $array as $item ){
        $out .= $before.$item.$after.$glue;
    }

    return substr($out, 0, -strlen($glue));
}
```

You can then do stuff like....

Implode the array values and append to your query string:

```
implode_wrapped('selectedItems[]=', '', '&amp;', $items);
```

Note that I'm using 'selectedItems[]'.  Your code - function searchLocations() - in its current form is **not** sending selectedItems as an array.

Implode and use with SQL:

```
implode_wrapped("'", "'", ',', $items);
```

Note that you need to sanitize any values that get sent to SQL or you **will** be hacked.